# difference between html tags and css stylesheet in shiny dashboard

Tags: css, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to understand why the following html tag works to change the background color of the body in a shiny dashboard:

```css
tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.content-wrapper, .right-side {background-color: blue}')))
```

but adding the following css to my stylesheet does not work:

```css
.content-wrapper, .right-side {background-color: blue}
```

My stylesheet is set up correctly, and is making changes to other parts of the app. Any insight into why the css does not work in this situaiton would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try with `!important`? (`{background-color: blue !important}`)

Comment: this worked! thank you!